# How to calculate the latency and bandwidth of a network

Tags: java, mpi

i have code that pings several machines, and records the time, it does this for various packet sizes ( 1kb to 100gb ), but i would like to know how to calculate the latency of the network, how can this be achieved ?

this is the code i am using to measure the ping :

also how can i measure the bandwidth of the system as well ?

Thanks for the help guys !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the ideal case where latency and bandwidth are fully constant, it's just a linear problem:

```
delay = packetsize / bandwidth + latency
```

There are two variables, bandwidth and latency, so you need at least two different records to solve it. However, I'd suggest to calculate them for many data pairs and e.g. take the median of all your results.

I think solving the above equation should be easy. If not, feel free to ask.

**Update:** How to solve the above equation

```
Let
y1, y2 values for delay
x1, x2 values for packetsize
a := 1/bandwith
b := latency

y1 = a * x1 + b
y2 = a * x2 + b
=> b = y1 - a * x1              [1]
=> y2 = a * x2 + y1 - a * x1
=> a = (y2 - y1) / (x2 + x1)
Now put it in equation [1]:
=> b = y1 - (y2 - y1) / (x2 + x1)
```

Now you have `b` for the latency and `1 / a` for the bandwidth.

Comment: Thanks a lot, the results for the delay, will all be run 20 times, and the lowest, highest and mean figures taken, i have will be able to use the delay medium, and the packet size, but how will i be able to work out the bandwidth and latency when i don't know either ?